# SQL Server Linked Server Openquery

Tags: sql-server, openquery

This my current code and is working fine.I need the proper syntax to make the fieldname a variable.
For example:

```
SET @firstname = ''' + @value + ''''

declare  @SQL NVARCHAR(4000),@listid nvarchar(50), @value nvarchar(50), @fieldname nvarchar(50)
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    set @listid = '80000003-1525450413'
    set @value = 'dennis4'
    set @fieldname = 'firstname'

set @SQL ='Update openquery(QRemote, ''select * from customer WHERE listID = ''''' + @listid + ''''''')
SET firstname = ''' + @value + ''''
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Firstname is a column within Quick Books. All I want is to make it a dynamic parameter. As you can see listID and value are parameters. I would Like to do the following:  SET @SQL2 = 'Set @fieldname = ''' + @value + '''' Then I can execute it with EXEC sp_executesql @sql + @sql2.

Comment: you want to do what?

Comment: You see line 9: "Set firstname = ''' + @value + '''. Firstname is a column in my table. I need to make that a parameter in which I will be passing down from MS Access.

Comment: Where would this fieldname be used? and what problem are you having just concatenating it to the string? You're already concatenating other things.

Comment: Firstname is a column within Quick Books. All I want is to make it a dynamic parameter. As you can see listID and value are parameters. I would Like to do the following:

Comment: Please try again to explain what you want to do. Is it the `set` part that you want to be dynamic or part of the `where` clause?